# Inserting dynamic fields data into db issue?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a field which is created dynamically, which works perfectly. I am currently trying to insert the data inputted into the dynamic field into my db. 
However, the information just will not insert into the db, i.e the submit button is not submitting.

I have copy and pasted the form in the jQuery and the php into a test file, removed the jQuery and the form inserts just as required.

My dynamic field is creating using jquery and i am trying to insert the data into the db using php, does jquery  and php work hand in hand? any suggestions or advice is much appreciated.

**Dynamic field**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var max_fields = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
            var wrapper = $(".input_fields"); //Fields wrapper
            var add_button = $(".add_field"); //Add button ID

            var x = 1; //initlal text box count
            $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
                e.preventDefault();
                if (x < max_fields) {
                    x++; //text box increment
                    $(wrapper).prepend('<div id="new_blue">\n\
                           <div id="inline" class="div">\n\\n\
                           <form id="form" class="Form" method="POST" action="" accept-charset="utf-8">\n\
                           <p id="option" class="text">Option name\n\
                           <input type="text" id="option_nme" name="option_nme[]" class="option_field"></p>\n\
                           </div>\n\
                           \n\
                           <div id="inl" class="div">\n\
                           <p id="customer" class="text">Allow customer to pick ..\n\
                           <select class="optionType" name="optionType" value=""disabled="disabled" >\n\
                           <option value="Option Type" disabled="disabled">Option Type</option>\n\
                           </select>\n\
                           </div>\n\
                           </p>\n\
                           <hr id="hoz_line">\n\
                           <p id="para">You can add add-ons after creating this option...\n\
                           </p>\n\
                           <input type="submit" id="dynamic_submit" name="dynamic_submit" value="Submit">\n\
                           <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>\n\\n\
                           </form></div>'); //add input box
                }
            });

            $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent('div').remove();
                x--;
            })
        });
```

**insert query**

```
  $dbc = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "One_Delivery");
    $dbc->set_charset("utf8mb4");

    $sel_sql = "SELECT Add_On_ID FROM Add_On";
    $sel_result = $dbc->query($sel_sql);

    if ($sel_result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($sell_row = $sel_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $ao_id = $sell_row['Add_On_ID'];
        }

        //insert dynamic field(s) into add-on
        if (isset($_POST['dynamic_submit'])) {
            $df_option_name = $_POST['option_nme'];

            // option name validation
            if (empty($_POST['option_nme'])) {
                $add_product_errors['option_nme'] = "Oops! i cannot be empty";
            }

            $ao_query = "INSERT INTO Add_on(Add_On_OpName) VALUES (?)
         ON DUPLICATE KEY 
         UPDATE
         Add_On_OpName = ?"; //on duplicate input update row
            //var_dump($databaseObject);
            $ao_run_query = $dbc->prepare($ao_query);

            $ao_run_query->bind_param('ss', $df_option_name, $df_option_name);
            // THIS now executes the above transaction, returns TRUE if successful - issdissd duplicate update
            if (!$ao_run_query->execute()) {
                $insertError = "There was an error inserting data: " . $ao_run_query->error;
            }

            print "affected rows:" . $ao_run_query->affected_rows; //how many records affected? 
            $ao_run_query->free_result(); // Frees memory on completion 
            $ao_run_query->close(); //closes this action 


        }
```

Comment: What errors are being output, either in the browser console (js) or via PHP?

Comment: @JamieBicknell no errors. It is just as if the submit button is disabled and i don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things:

Is the button outputted via AJAX? If so you'd need to listen like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_field', function(e) {
    // do stuff
});
```

You're also using `$()` twice on the `.add_field` this may have an effect, instead do:

```
$('.add_field').on('click', function(e) {
    // do stuff
});
```

or

```
$('.add_field').click(function(e) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Hi. The echo is echo'd out of the db, therefore it is html

Comment: What I was getting as is whether the HTML is inserted into the document via AJAX, if so then you either have to refresh the event listener to the button, or use the method I added